# Joining two tables on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables.

First table  represented below includes the Count of dialled call hour wise by certain number

```
+-------------+---------------+-------+
| Card_no     | Dialled_Count | Hour  |
+-------------+---------------+-------+
| 9913528756  |   9           |  10   |
| 9913528756  |   2           |  11   |
| 9913528756  |   10          |  23   |
+-------------+---------------+-------+
```

And the other table represents the Count of message sent hourwise.

```
+-------------+---------------+-------+
| Card_no     | Message_Count |  Hour |
+-------------+---------------+-------+
| 9913528756  |   5           |  6    |
| 9913528756  |   10          |  10   |
| 9913528756  |   12          |  17   |
+-------------+---------------+-------+
```

I want to join these tables with the  expected final result as :

```
+-------------+---------------+-------+--------------+
| Card_no     | Dialled_Count |  Hour | Message_count|
+-------------+---------------+-------+--------------+
| 9913528756  |   0           |  6    |   5          |
| 9913528756  |   9           |  10   |   10         |
| 9913528756  |   2           |  11   |   0          |
| 9913528756  |   0           |  17   |   12         |
| 9913528756  |   10          |  23   |   0          |
+-------------+---------------+-------+--------------+
```

Any helps are appreciated

Thanks in advance...

Comment: this is an outer join not an inner join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to use a [UNION ALL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) rather.

Somethign like

```
Select Card_No, Dialled_Count, hour, 0 as Message_Count from tblCall
union all
Select Card_No, 0 as Dialled_Count, hour, Message_Count from tblMessage
```

In response to the OP question, I would change the query to something like

```
SELECT  dl.Card_no,
        dl.Hour,
        IFNULL(c.Dialled_Count,0) Dialled_Count ,
        IFNULL(m.Message_count,0) Message_count
FROM    (
            SELECT  DISTINCT
                    Card_no,
                    Hour
            FROM    tblCall
            UNION 
            SELECT  DISTINCT
                    Card_no,
                    Hour
            FROM    tblMessage
        ) dl LEFT JOIN
        tblCall c   ON  dl.Card_no = c.Card_no
                    AND dl.Hour = c.Hour LEFT JOIN
        tblMessage m    ON  dl.Card_no = m.Card_no
                        AND dl.Hour = m.Hour
```

Comment: @pulchowkian Above solution should work, is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: @astander as stated in question there is a person who has send 10 messages and dialled 9 call in hour 10.Since Hour 10 is common in both table.I want the result in same row i.e 9913528756 | 9(call) |10(Hour) | 10(Mssg). But your query gave result as 9913528756 | 9(call) |10(Hour) | 0(Mssg) and 9913528756 | 0(call) |10(Hour) | 10(Mssg) in separate rows

Comment: @astander thanks edited query finally fulfilled my requirement

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.Card_no = b.Card_no
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM a RIGHT JOIN b ON a.Card_no = b.Card_no
```

This should work but you'll get NULLs and not 0s

Comment: This should work, and if he wants to get '0' instead of NULL, he can simply use CASE WHEN statement to switch them

Comment: @jtravaglini i have already tried before posting this question.But it gives me the result of Hour when both call and message was performed i.e. it gives me result of Hour 10 only

Comment: @pulchowkian my mistake, you're right - the full outer join (union) approach will work best for you